# Images are blurred in ImageList with ListView in window Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, window, imagelist

When I Set Some images of products in Imagelist and I set that Imagelist as LargeImageList of ListView for display of images.
At that time all are blur in ListView. I don't what is exactly happed with this images.

All images quality are good.
Even I set image without ListView then Quality is maintain with same image.

Here is the Image layout of my form and you can see images quality are degraded.

[Click here for see image](http://betterinfo.in/Image/capture.png)

```
foreach (var item in Data)
{
    {
        il.Images.Add("test1", image);
        ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
        lvOrderItem.Items.Add(lvi);
        lvOrderItem.Items[i].Name = item.ItemID.ToString();
        i++;
    }
}
lvOrderItem.MultiSelect = false;
lvOrderItem.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
il.ImageSize = new Size(125, 150);
lvOrderItem.View = View.LargeIcon;
lvOrderItem.LargeImageList = il;
```

Comment: is it asp, winform or wpf?

Comment: <pre>foreach (var item in Data)
                {
                    {  il.Images.Add("test1", image);
                        ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();                       
                        lvOrderItem.Items.Add(lvi);
                        lvOrderItem.Items[i].Name = item.ItemID.ToString();
                        i++;}}
lvOrderItem.MultiSelect = false;
lvOrderItem.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
il.ImageSize = new Size(125, 150);
lvOrderItem.View = View.LargeIcon;
lvOrderItem.LargeImageList = il;</pre>

Answer (score 0):

This problem is discussed [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1398375.aspx?display%20image%20in%20smaller%20size).
I'd recommend to store thumbnails together with original images and show it in in you image list. Also you can convert images on the fly.

Comment: No This is problem is created with window application.
what is exact solution for that.

I upload Jgp,png, gif Image.

For better solution you can see image